# Big data analytics references

Tags: bigdata

I'm looking for a good introductory book or course to big data analytics.
For the practical part, I'm particularly interested into using big data tools in R.

I would prefer a book, but other references are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why the question is on hold. I think that it does not belong to the class of "primarily opinion-based" (http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). This question asks for good references (books, tutorials, etc) that is quite common in stackexchange. Moreover, no similar questions have been posted right now (that is focusing on big data analytics in R). Then I call to reopen the question.

Comment: I'm one of the 2 close voters. My reason: `Big Data Analytics` is a very vague term, just like asking references for `Data Science`. It's very broad.  Instead, ask a pin-pointed question like, `References for tree-based methods`, `References for handling high-velocity streaming data`, etc :)

Comment: Hi Dawny33, big data analytics isn't a vague term. [Here](http://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/whitepapers/tdwi_bpreport_q411_big_data_analytics_tableau.pdf) it is defined as "the application of advanced analytic techniques to very big data sets", thus not all data mining techniques; "with big data analytics, the user is typically a business analyst who is trying to discover new business facts that no one in the enterprise knew before", so there is a well identified target. Moreover, I asked for **introductory** material, mainly books with R examples. Anyway, I appreciated your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to explore some of the best available resources, which includes online courses (Free/Paid), Books etc.

### Books

> - [Big Data and Analytics (WIND)](http://www.amazon.in/Data-Analytics-WIND-Seema-Acharya/dp/8126554789?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=30e388b6-c9fe-455b-83e2-c5020caeb097)
> - [Hadoop for Dummies](http://www.amazon.in/Hadoop-Dummies-Dirk-Deroos/dp/8126550511?ie=UTF8&redirect=true)
> - [Big Data for Dummies](http://www.amazon.in/Big-Data-Dummies-Judith-Hurwitz/dp/8126543280?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=30e388b6-c9fe-455b-83e2-c5020caeb097)
> - [Hadoop: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449311520)
> - [Learning Spark: Lightning-Fast Big Data Analysis](https://www.amazon.in/Learning-Spark-Lightning-Fast-Data-Analysis-ebook/dp/B00SW0TY8O?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0)
> - [MapReduce Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449327176)

### Online Courses

These are some best platforms that provide lots of courses with rich content and hands-on labs. You can go from beginner to expert level, followed by intermediate. (courses will be - Free/Paid  )

> - [Udemy - Big Data Analytics Courses](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?ref=home&src=ukw&q=Big%20data%20analytics%20&lang=en&instructionalLevel=beginner)
> - [Coursera - Big Data Analytics Courses](https://www.coursera.org/courses?_facet_changed_=true&languages=en&primaryLanguages=en&query=introduction%20to%20big%20data%20analytics)
> - [edX - Big Data Analytics Courses](https://www.edx.org/course/?search_query=Big%20data%20analytics&level=Introductory)
> - [Udacity - Data Analysis](https://www.udacity.com/courses/data-science)

### Other References

For more thoughts on that you might like to explore these websites-

> - [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-book-to-learn-Hadoop-for-beginners)
> - [Big Data - Made Simple](http://bigdata-madesimple.com/10-books-to-get-started-with-hadoop/)
> - [From Dev](http://www.fromdev.com/2014/07/Best-Hadoop-Books.html)
> - [KDnuggets](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2014/04/9-free-books-learning-data-mining-data-analysis.html)

### Update [BigData in R]

You can go through these references-

> - [Wikipedia - Programming with Big Data in R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_with_Big_Data_in_R)
> - [RStudio - Working with BigData in R](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/working-with-big-data-in-r/)
> - [InfoWorld - Learn To crunch BigData with R](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2880360/big-data/learn-to-crunch-big-data-with-r.html)

That's all from my side. Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, great answer, thanks! Can you suggest also any reference for using big data tools in R?

Comment: Hey, sure. I'll update the answer with sample references. Cheers! :)